# How to click link in webbrowser 

Tags: vb6, html, hyperlink, browser

i am trying to click a `div` `a` link in the webrowser in vb6 without success, the structure of the link is like this

```
<a class="classname">
    <div class="classname2"></div>
    <span class="span">spantext</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate DOM from outside like this

```
WebBrowser1.Application.Document.all("id_or_name").Click
```

or you can execute JScript to do whatever you want from inside like this

```
WebBrowser1.Application.Document.parentWindow.execScript "id_or_name.click();"
```

Comment: in this case, which one will be the `id` or `name`?

Comment: I think either will do. Try it yourself.